# How to add og:image meta tag only to specific page in BigCommerce

Tags: handlebars.js, meta-tags, bigcommerce

I want to add meta tag `og:image` to specific page in BigCommerce. I tried to do this by js (`document.location`) but there no results, it's added to HTML but in Facebook and other social networks doesn't work.

BigCommerce uses HandleBards.js so, as I understand I should to check what is the current page or URL page, but I don't know how I can check this in HandleBards.js